# Travel from Krabi to Koh Yao Yai

Tags: public-transport, thailand, ferries, krabi

Later this month I will be traveling to Koh Yao Yai from Krabi Airport. As online travel information is either dated, fragmented across different websites or both, I was wondering if someone here could tell me whether the information I found online is still current.

According to [Wikitravel](https://wikitravel.org/en/Ko_Yao) and [Travelfish](https://www.travelfish.org/transport/thailand/southern_thailand/phang_nga/ko_yao_yai/all), songthaew frequently drive between Krabi Airport and Krabi, Ao Nang. Supposedly there are two piers from which ferries leave for the Koh Yao islands.

Is this still the recommended way to travel? Any advice on getting around, departure times and ticket prices would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information as stated on those websites is still current. I ended up paying about 300 baht for a one-way trip to Koh Yao Yai via speedboat.